# Add dynamic number of SelectMultipleField's to wtf-flask form

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I've looked at the documentation and a couple other Q/As on here but I can't seem to make the code work.  I have a basic form in a forms.py file:

```
class SimpleForm(Form):
    list_of_files = ['Option 1','Option 2','Option 3','Option 4','Option 5','Option 6']
    files = [(x, x) for x in list_of_files]
    acheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label',choices=files)
    third_list = ['Special Analysis']
    third_files = [(x, x) for x in third_list] 
    bcheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label', choices=third_files)
    category_1 = SelectField(u'', choices=())
    category_2 = SelectField(u'', choices=())
    category_3 = SelectField(u'', choices=())
```

(I populate the categories later).  I also call this form in my views.py file.

```
form = SimpleForm()
```

I want to dynamically add several SelectMultipleField's (depending on the # of columns in an user uploaded csv file).  I want to pass a list variable (category) with the names of the columns n=1-5 and generate that many fields with another list (unique_values) which are the values of that field.  I was looking at the doc and tried to come up with this:

```
class F(Form):
    pass

    F.category = SelectMultipleField('category')
    for name in extra:
        setattr(F, name, SelectMultipleFields(name.title()))
    form = F(request.POST, ...)
```

I know it's not right.  How do I modify to append SelectMultipleField's to my original "SimpleForm?"
I ultimately want to generate n numbers of the following:

```
unique_values = [('1', 'Choice1'), ('2', 'Choice2'), ('3', 'Choice3')]
category_4 = SelectMultipleField(u"",choices=unique_values)
```

***UPDATE:*** 
To call the form on *views.py*, I use the following:

```
select_dict = {'Geography': ['US', 'Asia', 'Europe'], 'Product Type': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}
form= F(request.form,select_dict)
```

My subclass (on *forms.py*) is:

```
class F(SimpleForm):
pass
#select_dict could be a dictionary that looks like this: {category_+str(col_number): set of choices}
def __init__(self, select_dict, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SimpleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print(select_dict)
    for name,choices in select_dict.items():
        test = [(x, x) for x in choices]
        setattr(F, name, SelectMultipleField(name.title(),choices=test))
```

I'm getting the following error: "formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper that supports the 'getlist' method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to do is append to `SimpleForm` a variable number of `SelectMultipleField` elements, each with a different choice set.

First of all, to add the `SelectMultipleField` elements to the original `SimpleForm` you should just subclass it (instead of the original `Form`) when you define `F`.

Second of all, you can use most of the code you already wrote, like so:

```
class F(SimpleForm):
    pass

#select_dict could be a dictionary that looks like this: {category_+str(col_number): set of choices}
for name,choices in select_dict.items():
    setattr(F, name, SelectMultipleFields(name.title(),choices=choices))

form = F(request.POST, ...)
```

To render the dynamic form in the template, you will need a custom Jinja filter (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436841/display-all-jinja-object-attributes)) and maybe a simpler way to render a field (like described on [this page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/)).

Comment: I'm super close from this....How do I actually implement on the views page?  I can definitely do the {{for field in form}} but what are the actual names of the entities?  Previously, I'll call by 'form.category_4' but what are the jinja names here?

Comment: You use flask-WTForms?

Comment: I mistyped.  i mean the html page.  For instance, for the defined forms, I'll write    {{ form.category_1}}.  How do i do this for the dynamic fields whose names will be different.

Comment: @Phillip details in my answer.

Comment: Got that to work when select_dict is defined on the forms.py page.  Trying to pass that 'select_dict' value from my views page....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually just figured it out. I switched the order of request.form and select_dict.  Your answer worked perfectly.  I just added ".items()" on select_dict.

Comment: @Phillip just noticed this. My mistake, sorry for the inconvenience. Edited the answer.